# Should Stack Overflow tell users with Magento-related questions of borderline quality to come here?

Tags: discussion, support, migration

When I see a Magento question on Stack Overflow that doesn't belong there (i.e. it has no programming aspect *at all* or is extremely specialized) I tend to tell them to go to http://magento.stackexchange.com and ask there. I try to filter a bit - if it's an extremely low quality question, I will just vote to close. But even with that, most of the questions that we are talking about are of.... borderline quality.

SO's sending users with questions of less-than-perfect quality to  other, smaller sites in the network has [caused trouble in the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl) because those new users were perceived as drowning the place with their questions.

Does Magento.SE have problems with its incoming user / question base, or is it more tolerant towards questions like "how do I implement feature X???????" or "X feature in my Magento install doesn't work???????"

tl;dr: Should experienced users on Stack Overflow continue recommending Magento.SE to people  with relatively little discrimination, or should great care be taken that the questioner has an actual high quality question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From my understanding of the intentions of starting our own magento.SE is to have a site dedicated to Magento since not all Magento questions are necessarily SO relevant.

In that spirit I would say send every one our way and if we feel the users did not make enough of an effort we will for sure let them know.

> Does Magento.SE have problems with its incoming user / question base,
>   or is it more tolerant towards questions like "how do I implement
>   feature X???????" or "X feature in my Magento install doesn't
>   work???????"

I personally don't mind "how do I implement feature X?" questions. Most answers would not include full fledged working code examples but would rather outline an approach in broad strokes. This is something that even I as an experienced Magento developer can learn from and find valuable.

Comment: I totally agree. I often ask those "how to implement feature x" questions here and prefer answers the provide an approach.